# Why does a java.lang.reflect.Proxy require declaring checked exceptions when normal method invocation does not?

Tags: java, reflection

Java's `Proxy` requires that any checked exceptions thrown from the backing `InvocationHandler` are declared on the interface method that is currently being invoked.

For example, given a test interface,

```java
interface Foo {
  void bar1();
  void bar2() throws IOException;
}
```

An `Proxy`-based instance backed by an `InvocationHandler` that always throws `IOException` produces two behaviors:

- `bar1()` will throw an unchecked `UndeclaredThrowableException` with the `IOException` as its cause.
- `bar2()` will throw the `IOException` directly.

Now, implement this interface with a normal class and throw `IOException` from both methods¹. Callers to either method will receive the `IOException` thrown directly.

Why does a `Proxy` enforce checked exceptions at runtime when seemingly no other part of the VM does?

---

*Note*: this case is distinctly different than methods which are *forced* to wrap checked exceptions in order to throw them which is commonly seen in patterns like

```java
} catch (e: IOException) {
  throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
}
```

¹ Either by using the "sneaky throw" technique, writing it in a language without checked exceptions like Kotlin, or implementing the class directly in bytecode.

Comment: I guess it's just design choice, java likes to add weird stuff like that. Idea was to probably prevent pure java code from getting checked exceptions in places where this should not be possible - as sneaky throw didn't exist back then (proxy API was created before generics existed), and other compilators and manual bytecode manipulation is not something that was expected either. (Instrumentation was also added later)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what an answer could look like here. But the code that causes the `UndeclaredThrowableException` to be thrown is generated generically, based on the exceptions that are *declared*. Only the ones that are declared will be received normally. The ones that are *not* declared will be considered as "any throwable", which is caught and wrapped as a last resort. The relevant code is e.g. at https://github.com/JetBrains/jdk8u_jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/misc/ProxyGenerator.java#L971

Comment: Your footnote proves that the technique you refer to isn't supported by the base language in either case. Of course any sneaky technique is going to sneak past. Unclear what you're really asking here.

Comment: @user207421 The language choice is irrelevant. I can rewrite the question framed from bytecode and it wouldn't require a footnote. This is behavior of the VM.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that this is just a design choice like many others.
Idea was to probably prevent pure java code from getting checked exceptions in places where this should not be possible - as sneaky throw didn't exist back then (proxy API was created before generics existed, and sneaky throw works thanks to generic type erasure), and other compilators and manual bytecode manipulation is not something that was expected either. (Instrumentation was also added later)
So when proxy classes were created no one would expect to get checked exception from unchecked method, so it only sounds natural to make it work the same way for proxy classes.

And still in java the idea is to not allow for checked exceptions to be thrown randomly, the fact that JVM does not prevent this on lower lever is a different thing - but language should try to stay as consistent as possible.
And checked exceptions are part of java specification, not jvm itself, so other languages can do whatever they want - but proxy classes are part of java sdk so they should follow java specification.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2.3